# Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

Before i start I want to say this, I am in NO WAY a developer/scripter/coder or whatever you wanna call it. Anyways, i am trying to make a kick command and it *works* but it says: `Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null.` And I'm worried it's letting anyone kick people, even though it hasn't happened yet, that's what it seems like. Here is the code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
        if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}kick`)) {
            let member = message.mentions.members.first();
            member.kick().then(member)
                message.channel.send(member.displayName + " was kicked.")
        }
})
```

Comment: the value of `message.member` is null. You should log the value of `message` and see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: It looks like your message has no member property.

Comment: Is message an object?

Comment: i really dont know what that means, this entire script is from a tutorial except i changed a few parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `hasPermission` on `message.member`.  This suggests that `message.member` is `null`, at least some of the times this is called.

You can try changing to:

```
    if(message.member && message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
```

and that should make sure `message.member` has a value before you try to dereference it.  If there's no `member` then it won't do anything.

I'm not sure how the discord APIs work so I don't know if this is an expected state things could be in (or if `member` is the right field to be looking at), so if this is always happening then you should make sure that's correct.

Also, I suspect this bit is wrong:

```
            member.kick().then(member)
                message.channel.send(member.displayName + " was kicked.")
```

and should probably be:

```
            member.kick().then(member => 
                message.channel.send(member.displayName + " was kicked."));
```